# Schwarzian derivative from conformal factor

Tags: conformal-field-theory, differentiation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Suppose I have a 2D Lorentzian conformally flat metric

$$ ds^2 = -\Omega(u, v) du dv.$$

I consider a conformal field theory whose stress-energy tensor $T_{ab}$ is known on the flat metric

$$ds^2 = -dudv.$$

Under a conformal transformation the holomorphic part of the stress-energy tensor changes according to

$$ T'(w) = \left(\frac{dw}{dz} \right)^{-2} \left[T(z) - \frac{c}{12} \{w;z\} \right]$$

I would like to apply this to find $T_{ab}$ in the conformally-flat metric, given knowledge of it in the actually-flat one. But it is unclear to me how to use knowledge of the Weyl factor $\Omega(u,v)$ to compute the Schwarzian derivative.

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Comment: Well, you need to know the function $\Omega$ if you want to know the function $w=w(z)$, right?

Comment: Yes, I do know the function(s) I am interested in. Are you saying there is no way to answer this question in the general case?

Comment: this is a good question and yes this can be done. but note that for a general conformally flat metric one can find a flat metric only at a point due to the presence of curvature. i will try to find some time to write-up the answer (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: @Wakabaloola Thank you! Can you explain what you mean by "find a flat metric"? If you mean "find a flat metric by performing a diffeomorphism", I agree. But I had thought that by definition conformally flat metrics were flat up to a Weyl transformation?

Comment: Yes, you interpret my comment as I intended. Note that there is a global obstruction to setting the metric to be globally flat by a diffeomorphism, so this can only be done at a point for a general conformal factor. One can always however perform a diffeomorphism to make the metric "as flat as possible" at any given point (I hope to write-up the relevant details).

Comment: When you add Weyl to the story then one must solve a differential equation for the Weyl factor that sets the Ricci scalar to zero, but this requires global information (because of boundary conditions). But since the Euler number is a topological invariant, and since this is related to an integral of the Ricci scalar, there is a global obstruction to setting the Ricci scalar to zero everywhere, even when you include Weyl in addition to Diffeomorphisms.